# showing status bar first to show progress

Tags: c#

Im creating a c# windows form and ive come accross a problem.

When the window opens I am wanting to run a bit of code which can make the front console appear to freeze. The code runs fine but I want to show the status of the program in the status strip at the bottom of the page. I am running the code in the action Form.Shown. However the code does not update the status bar until everything is shown. I can change the label no problem.

How would I go about loading the window and then running the code and updating the status bar (like a background task)?

What areas would I need to look at to get this information?

Comment: you can use `Application.DoEvent()` but I suggest you to use `BackgroundWorker`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do this

Set the `WorkerReportsProgress` property to true and in the DoWork eventhandler raise the ReportProgress event

in the eventhandler for the ProgressChanged place your logic to update your progresbar

there is a example on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#code-snippet-2)

Comment: where would you reccomend starting the background process? in the chown event?

Comment: depends when you when you want the process to start if you want it to start only if the form is shown use the Shown event, if you want it to start when you create the form do it in the constructor

Comment: cheers, on another note I am trying to update a checkbox list, assing more items to it but it produces an error.                     this.checklist.Items.Add(listarray[j]); is what im tring to do and apparntly i need to make it thread safe. any idea how?

Comment: that's because you can't access controls that were added using a different thread, you could probably use the form's [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute logic safely on the form's thread using the [`Dispatcher.Invoke(Action)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199416(v=vs.110).aspx) method

also if my answer helped you please mark it as the answer

Comment: Ive found out how to do it, I will mark it when ive tested it and I know it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Multithreading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx) to avoid freezing the forms. It means, you separate your form and the code (that you want to run in parallel) in different threads so that the form doesn't wait for the code completes. You can monitor the progress of the code via events.